# Error during Sonar Configuration ( use Derby default DB )

Tags: hudson, derby, sonarqube, hudson-plugins

I changed my Sonar DB from Oracle to Default Derby. I successfully configured the Sonar Server, however I have error during the integration with Hudson.

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: SQL driver not found oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    at org.sonar.jpa.session.DriverDatabaseConnector.getConnection(DriverDatabaseConnector.java:91)
    at org.sonar.jpa.session.AbstractDatabaseConnector.testConnection(AbstractDatabaseConnector.java:185)
    ... 41 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:200)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:188)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:251)
    at org.sonar.jpa.session.DriverDatabaseConnector.getConnection(DriverDatabaseConnector.java:88)
    ... 42 more
```

Error states that I can't found OracleDriver, Which I should not use anymore.

In my Hudson configuration, I have removed my oracle configuration and replaced it with these :
[image]

Any idea on what I configured wrongly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fixed by changing the driver to "org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver". Turns out that the remarks "Do not set if you use default embedded" is a misleading.

Comment: The client driver is not the same as the embedded driver. Since your URL includes //moonint02:1527, you are using the client driver, not the embedded driver, and hence you had to specify the client driver classname. To use the embedded driver, your connection URL would not include a host:port, just the path to the database.